# "firebase" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: firebase, hosting

Estoy tratando de usar el hosting de firebase.
He puesto en la consola: `npm install -g firebase-tools`. Ahora pongo `firebase login` y la consola me dice:
*"firebase" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.*

¿Cómo soluciono esto para que la consola me reconozca el término "firebase"?

Comment: Creo que tiene algo que ver con la variable de entorno, pero no sé que ruta poner.

Comment: Ya instalaste 'firebase' con el comando `npm i firebase --save`?

Comment: Necesitas instalar ambas dependencias, tanto `firebase` como `firebase-tools`

Comment: @RimuruTempest: ok, acabo de introducir el comando  `npm i -g firebase --save`, después vuelvo a poner el comando `firebase login`y me sale el mismo mensaje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes de instalar `firebase-tools`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-npm

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 3):

**Esto fue lo que me funcionó a mi en Windows 10.**

Primero que nada escribes el comando

```
npm get prefix
```

y copias toda la ruta que te devuelva, que en mi caso fue:

> C:\Users\usuario\.npm-global

luego de eso sigue esta ruta:

panel de control > sistema > configuracion avanzada del sistema > variables de entorno.

Seleccionas la que diga PATH y le das click en Editar, luego click en Nuevo y pegas la ruta que anteriormente copiaste. Le das click en Aceptar en todas las ventanas para cerrarlas. Por ultimo reinicia tu pc (o simplemente la terminal, yo reinicie la pc) y una vez reiniciada escribes el comando:

```
firebase --version
```

te tiene que mostrar la versión de firebase que en mi caso es la 6.0.0

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes ejecutar el comando "firebase init" o "firebase login" desde la carpeta de tu proyecto.

Comment: edita tu respuesta para mostrar solo una solucion final, si conseguiste resolver el problema con la segunda parte elimina la primera asi no confunde tanto. Un  saludo :)

Comment: Exelente Solucion... Maestrooooo..!! Mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como estas?

Actualmente solo uso firebase como storage y tenia este mismo error, solo debe asegurarte de tener instalado lo siguiente:

```
 npm install firebase
```

y por ultimo:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

En mi caso funciono